# .htaccess - delete characters from URL and redirect

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I need help modify a file *.htaccess* delete characters from URL and redirect.
The file *.htaccess* is currently empty.

1. I want to change the word `article` to the word `topic` in all the URLs.

The current URL:

```
www.example.com/index.php?action=article&cat_id=011&id=37&lang=en
```

1. I want to delete the last characters of the URLs `&lang=en` and some URLs `&lang=`

The current URLs:

```
www.example.com/index.php?action=article&cat_id=011&id=37&lang=en
www.example.com/?action=article&cat_id=011&id=37&lang=
```

So the final URL:

```
www.example.com/index.php?action=topic&cat_id=011&id=37
www.example.com/?action=topic&cat_id=011&id=37
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

With the following code:

- Line 1: Just a block header comment to explain what happens in the code snippet
- Line 2: Requires a parameter match of the `action=article` value pair;
- Line 3: Captures the `cat_id` value into parameter `%2`.
- Line 4: Captures the `id` value into parameter `%5`.
- Line 5: Could be used to capture the `lang` value (commented out / not in use).
- Line 6: Rewrites internally to a hard-coded URL with parameters specified.

If you wished to use the `lang` value at some point in the future you would simply need to append `&lang=%8` to the end of line 6 and remove the `#` comment prefix from line 5.

```
# Change action parameter value from article to topic and drop lang parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=article
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?cat_id=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?lang=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ index.php?action=topic&cat_id=%2&id=%5
```